# Truncating GNU Umac32 output length

Tags: java, cryptography, aes

I'm using the GNU crypto class called `UMac32` to create Message Authentication Codes. You can read the documentation here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-crypto/manual/api/gnu/crypto/mac/UMac32.html

It is working now, but I'd like to be able to get a shorter output. There is a field inherited from the interface `Imac` called `TRUNCATED_SIZE` that I thought that I could use to do, but it is not working as expected.

Here is my code:

```
String message = "Hello World!";
String MAC_KEY_MATERIAL = "gnu.crypto.mac.key.material";
String TRUNCATED_SIZE = "gnu.crypto.mac.truncated.size";
String NONCE_MATERIAL = "gnu.crypto.umac.nonce.material";

Map attributes = new HashMap();
attributes.put(MAC_KEY_MATERIAL, PRIVATE_KEY.getBytes());
attributes.put(TRUNCATED_SIZE, 4);
attributes.put(NONCE_MATERIAL, PRIVATE_NONCE.getBytes());

uMac32.init(attributes);

byte[] data = message.getBytes("ASCII");
uMac32.update(data, 0, message.length());
uMac32.digest();
```

From the `digest()` function I'm getting a byte array with a length of 8.

Is it possible to get a shorter result using this class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It *may* be okay to just truncate the value (I don't know how this mac works so I am not completely sure). But I'd question if it would wise to make it even shorter than 8bytes. Assuming the MAC is ideal then with 64bits you get an acceptable security of 2^63 tries on average for a message tag forgery. If you reduce it to, say, 4 bytes that shortens to only 2^31 ~= 2Billion messages on average to insert an invalid but authenticated message.

Comment: Assuming a message is about 100bytes large this puts an attack in the range of only about 200gb traffic for an online service. That may or may not be an acceptable risk for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the code of the UMac32 class](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/gnu/javax/crypto/mac/UMac32.java.html):

```
for (int i = 0; i < OUTPUT_LEN; i++)
{
    result[i] = (byte) (result[i] ^ pad[i]);
}
```

Where `OUTPUT_LEN` is defined as a constant with value 8. The `UMAC-OUTPUT-LEN` defined in the JavaDoc is not a configurable parameter of the implementation but one for the UMAC algorithm (as Perseids has clarified).

So the only thing you can do is to truncate the result manually. This is something that is actually cryptographically sound; hashes and MAC authentication tags are often truncated, leaving just the least significant (leftmost) bytes. However, a tag of 8 bytes is approximately the minimum already; anything less will lessen the cryptographic strength of the function.

Comment: That's what I thought I should do. I wanted to be sure that it was the right way to do so. So, if I need a shorter tag I will truncate it manually. Thanks a lot!